# How to convert custom time "ticks" to TDateTime?

Tags: c++, datetime

*(i'm using C++Builder 2006, if this matters)*

I'm not able to solve this problem:

What i have (and i cannot change this):

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t Leaps; // How many Leaps from the previous event (see below)
    uint16_t Ticks; // Event "machine ticks" (see below)
    uint16_t Code;
} sMachineEvents;

typedef struct {
    TDateTime Date;
    uint16_t Code;
} sConvertEvents;

TDateTime Sync // Contains the date and time of Ev1
TICKS_PER_SECOND // #defined elsewhere: How many Ticks in a second
TICKS_PER_LEAP // #defined elsewhere: How many ticks to make a "Leap"
               // (this means that when the Tick counter reaches TICKS_PER_LEAP
               //  it becomes 0 and the Leaps counter increases by 1)


sMachineEvents Ev[3];
sConvertEvents cEv[3];

Ev[0].Leaps = 0x0005;
Ev[0].Ticks = 0x5975;
Ev[0].Code  = 0x0001;

Ev[1].Leaps = 0x0001;
Ev[1].Ticks = 0x0124;
Ev[1].Code  = 0x0002;

Ev[2].Leaps = 0x0000;
Ev[2].Ticks = 0x70AC;
Ev[2].Code  = 0x0003;
```

I need to "convert" these "MachineEvents" in "ConvertEvents".
The first one is easy:

```
cEv[0].Date = Sync;
cEv[0].Code = Ev[0].Code;
```

Now: Ev[1] happened BEFORE Ev[0].

How much? I need to go "back in time" by Ev[0].Leaps+Ev[0].Ticks and then go "forward in time" by Ev[1].Ticks.

Ev[2] is the same: it happened

```
Ev[1].Leaps + Ev[1].Ticks - Ev[2].Ticks
```

BEFORE Ev[1]....

HOW should I compute the DateTime for Ev[1] and Ev[2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDateTime is actually a floating point value representing the number of days; an hour is represented by `1.0 / 24.0`, and a second is represented by `1.0 / SecsPerDay` (`SecsPerDay` is a constant equal to `60 * 60 * 24 = 86400`).

So, if one tick is `1.0 / TICKS_PER_SECOND` seconds:

```
TDateTime TimeAsTDateTime = TimeInTicks / (SecsPerDay * TICKS_PER_SECOND)
```

Also, I think your code is not correct: instead of `Ev[0].Leaps+Ev[0].Ticks`, as far as I can see you need to use `Ev[0].Leaps * TICKS_PER_LEAP + Ev[0].Ticks`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you compare "ticks" with "time".
You have to convert the ticks in time format, done by `tick_count / TICKS_PER_SECOND`

So `float Seconds = Tick / TICKS_PER_SECOND`. As it is a float, you might better use Milliseconds

```
int ms = (int)(ticks / TICKS_PER_SECOND * 1000);
```

With the Seconds (or Milliseconds) you can create a new Date object and add the two Date Objects, or simply add the seconds to the old Date.

Another way would be saving all Ticks since start of the program and simply using this as "Date Reference".